# How to save outputs in every step using while_loop with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build a RNN with thousands of timesteps, so the proper way is to use the while_loop function since the GPU will be out of memory in for loops.

But I could not find a way to save rnn outputs in every step. I tried using a global list or using tf.concat() to accumulate the output. Neither worked. It seems like while_loop() can only be used to get the final output.

Is there any solution to get all the outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` which does exactly this using `while_loop` and `TensorArray` objects.